# Git Pull results in new merge

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm working on a new machine and for some reason now when I pull this creates a new merge commit for the changes I am pulling down. This has never happened to me before and I'm doing nothing different to before.

In SourceTree for example if I pull with 'Commit merged changes immediately' deselected this results in uncommitted changes which are the changes that were already merged onto our develop branch in the PR.

[image]

If I do the pull via Terminal I get this message:

```
Merge branch 'develop' of bitbucket.org:redacted/ into develop
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

So this tells me it's not a SourceTree issue but I have no idea what's going on.

Any help would be appreciated but please ELI5 as I'm no expert on Git.

Comment: What does it display if you type the following in the terminal? `git config merge.ff`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your old machine had `pull.rebase true` and the new machine doesn't.

I suggest running `git config --list --show-origin` and examining config files your old machine for config settings that you want to migrate to your new machine.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have finally been able to check and the old laptop didn't have this config set, I tried setting it anyway and it seemingly resolved the issue when pulling from the current branch but created a new rebasing issue when pulling from an untracked branch unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this: `git pull` literally means *run `git fetch`, then run `git merge` or some other second command of my choice*.  You should therefore expect `git pull` to make merge commits.  The surprise should be that you *didn't* get merge commits before!  I personally believe that Git newbies should not be told to use `git pull`.  It's not that running the two commands that `git pull` combines for you is any easier, but rather, that when you *do* use the two commands, you get a better sense of what's going on.

#### What's going on

The first thing you should have been told about Git (but probably weren't) is that Git is not about *files*, and not about *branches:* Git is all about *commits*.  Files come into the picture because commits would be useless without them, so each commit *holds* files.  Branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—come into the picture because the true names of individual commits are horrible, and humans really don't want to (and should not) use them directly, most of the time.  But Git is all about the commits, so we need to know what a commit is, and what it does for us.

Each commit:

- Is numbered, with a huge and random-looking number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  For instance, [`9bf691b78cf906751e65d65ba0c6ffdcd9a5a12c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bf691b78cf906751e65d65ba0c6ffdcd9a5a12c) is a commit in a Git repository for Git.  Git calls this a *hash ID*, or more formally an *object ID* or OID.

  The number here is *unique:* no other commit, in any Git repository anywhere in the universe, is ever allowed to use that number again.  That number was first used for *that* commit, and if you have a commit with that number in *your* repository, it's required that it be *that* commit.  Git somehow manages to do this across all Git repositories that exist anywhere in the universe, without having any of the repositories talk to any other repository.

  This trick is literally mathematically impossible to keep up forever, and someday Git will fail, but by making the hash ID huge, we can hope that the day will be so many billions of years in the future that we won't care because we're all long since dead.
- Is read-only.  This is required to make the numbering scheme work.
- Holds two things:

  - Every commit holds (indirectly) a full snapshot of every file.  These files are stored in a special, compressed, read-only, Git-only, *de-duplicated* format.  This makes every commit act like an archive (a tar or WinRAR or zip file) of all files.  The de-duplication trick means that most commits, which mostly re-use most of the files from previous commits, are *tiny*.  Only all-new content for some file requires any space at all.  Well, that plus the ...
  - Metadata: every commit holds some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  It also includes other stuff, e.g., some date-and-time stamps.

Git stores all these commits in a big database.  This is a simple [key-value store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database), where the hash ID of the commit is the key.  So Git *needs* the hash ID to retrieve the actual commit.

Git adds something to this metadata for Git's own purposes: every commit stores, in this metadata, a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.  This list is usually just one entry long, which makes the commit an *ordinary commit*.  One other kind of commit is a *root commit:* one with *no* previous hash ID, i.e., and empty list of parents.  The very first commit in any Git repository is a root commit (and often the only one).  The third kind of commit is a *merge* commit, where the list has two or more parent hash IDs.  But most commits are ordinary, single-parent commits.

When a commit stores the hash ID of some earlier commit, we say that the later commit *points to* the earlier commit.  We can draw that as an arrow sticking out of a commit.  Let's pick some ordinary commit's hash ID and just call it `H` for "hash" and draw that:

```
            <-H
```

This arrow *points to* the previous commit, which is also an ordinary commit and therefore has some hash ID and snapshot and parent.  Let's call this one `G`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Like `H`, `G` points to yet another, still-earlier commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

If `H` is the *last* commit in this chain—i.e., the commit we made most recently, just now—then the chain *ends* at commit `H`.  It keeps going backwards from there, to commit `G`, then `F`, then `E`, and so on, until it finally reaches the very *first* commit—presumably `A`—which doesn't point backwards any further:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H
```

where we get a little lazy about drawing the arrows.  (Humans sometimes wish they went forwards, instead of backwards, and we can be sloppy about drawing the commits because they're literally unchangeable and if we have the right ones, we know the arrows really only go backwards.  It's obvious, after the fact, that they have to: we don't know what some *future* commit's hash ID will be—because of the time stamps, it literally depends on the exact second we wind up making the commit—but we know what some *past* commit's hash ID *is*.)

#### Branch names

The problem with this particular scheme is that to use Git this way, we'd literally have to memorize the hash ID for commit `H`.  Git *needs* a hash ID to *find* a commit, in its big database full of commit objects and other supporting objects.  It only really needs the *last* one, because `H` contains `G`'s hash ID, so as long as we can tell Git how to find `H`, Git can use `H` to find `G`.  Git can then use `G` to find `F`, and so on, all the way back to the beginning of the repository.  But we need to write down, or otherwise memorize, `H`'s hash ID.

But hold on: we have a *computer*.  Let's add a second key-value database, next to the big one full of commits and other objects, where the keys are *names*, such as branch names, tag names, and other kinds of names.  We'll have each name store *exactly one* hash ID.  That's all we need, so we'll make it a crappy kind of database (well, that's what Git does anyway; this has become a problem and someday Git will have a better database here), where a *branch name* stores *one* hash ID, for the *last* commit.

Let's draw that in:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
```

We now have one *branch name*, `main`, pointing to commit `H`.  We'll keep this arrow as an arrow, for reasons that should become obvious in a moment.

Now, to make Git more *useful*, we'll add more branch names.  Let's create a branch named `dev` or `develop` or whatever, or `feature`, or whatever we like, maybe just `br1`.  This name must point to some commit: that's how branch names are defined, in Git.  Which commit should we pick?  Probably the latest one, `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, main
```

We now have a minor issue: which *branch name* are we using?  For the moment it doesn't seem to matter, but let's fix this issue by attaching the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase, to exactly one branch name:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, main (HEAD)
```

This means we are "on" branch `main`, while both *names* hold `H`'s hash ID.

**Exercise:**  Which branch are the commits on, `main`, or `br1`?  **Warning: this is a trick question!**

Git's answer is: these commits are on *both branches*.  All the commits up through `H` are on two branches.

Let's add a third branch name, `br3`:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main (HEAD)
```

*All three names* select commit `H`, and all the commits are now on *three* branches.  If you're starting to think that branch names are kind of silly and the idea of being "on a branch" doesn't seem to mean anything, well, you're exactly right.

**The point of a branch name is to be able to quickly find one specific commit.**  Git calls this commit the *tip commit* of that branch.  So `H` is the tip commit of all three branches: right now, all three names find commit `H`.  We're about to change this though!

Let's now switch to branch `br1`, with `git switch br1` or `git checkout br1`.  The result is this:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2, main
```

Nothing much has changed yet: we're still *using* commit `H`.  We're just using it *through the name `br1`*.

You already know how to make a new commit, so let's do that right now: we'll change some files around and `git add` and run `git commit` and get a new commit.  This new commit will get some new, unpredictable, random-looking hash ID, but we'll just call it `I`, using the next letter.

Because we *were* using commit `H`, Git will make new commit `I` point backwards *to* commit `H`.  Then, having made the new commit and obtained its hash ID in the process, Git will stuff the new commit's hash ID *into the current branch name*.  The result looks like this:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

Commit `I` is on branch `br1`.  Commit `H` is ... well, it's *still on all three branches*.

Let's make another new commit just for the heck of it:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

Name `br1` now points to `J`, making `J` the tip commit of branch `br1`.  `J` points back to `I`, `I` points back to `H`, and so on; and names `br2` and `main` point to `H`, so that `H` is the tip commit of those two branches.

Now let's use `git switch br2` to get "on" branch `br2`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD), main
```

When we do this, we find that Git *takes away* the commit-`J` files (this is safe as they're all permanently archived *in* commit `J`) and replaces them with the commit-`H` files.  This is one of the ways that Git makes commits and branch names useful: commit `H` is now the most recent `br1` commit, so those are the files we have now.

When we make another commit in the usual way, our new commit gets a new hash ID, but we'll just call it `K`.  New commit `K` points back to the commit we're using as we make it, i.e., to commit `H`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We make yet another commit and get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We have some major branching stuff going on now!

#### Merging

We can now run `git merge`.  Let's copy the whole repository somewhere so that we can erase our work and start over, so that we can see how `git merge` is ... weird.  But we'll start by merging `br1` and `br2`.

Now, the *goal* of `git merge` is simple.  **The goal of a merge is to combine work.**  We did some work on `br1`, and we did some (probably different) work on `br2`.  We want to combine this work.  For concreteness, let's say we changed file `f1.ext` in `I`, `f2.ext` in `J`, `f3.ext` in `K`, and `f1.ext` (again, but differently this time) in `L`.

Every commit holds a *snapshot* of all files—an archive of the files as they were at the time we made the commit.  So we could compare what's in commit `J` to what's in commit `L` to see what's different.  If we do, we'll see that files `f1` through `f3` are different.  **But this doesn't really help.**  The difference between `f3` in `J` and `f3` in `L` is in fact what we changed, which is great, but the difference between `f2` in `J` and `f2` in `L` would *back out* what we did in `J`.

We could reverse the diff, comparing `L` to `J`.  Now we'd get the right difference for `f2`, but for `f3`, the change would *back out* what we did in `L`!  And in both cases, the difference in `f1` doesn't work out right.

What we need is to somehow express *what we changed* in `br1` as a diff from some point where *all the files in both branches were the same*.  Is there such a point?  Well, yes, of course.  If you think about this for a moment, and look back at our drawings of commits above, you'll see that commits `A` through `H` are on *both branches*, and *all the files in those commits are obviously the same on both branches* because there's just the one commit `A` on both branches, and just the one commit `B` on both branches, and so on.

What we want to do—or more precisely, want *Git* to do—now becomes clear, or at least clear-*er:* we'll pick one *shared* commit, where the files are by definition the same in *both branches*, and have Git run `git diff` starting with this shared commit.  We'd like the *best* such shared commit, and whether that's obvious or not, it turns out to be the rightmost (latest) such commit, i.e., commit `H`, just before the two branches forked.

So, we'll have Git run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what changed on br1
```

The output from this diff will show our changes to files f1 and f2.

Then we'll separately have Git run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what changed on br2
```

The output from this diff will show our changes to files f1 and f3.

**Now we'll just have Git *combine the changes*.**

That's it!  It's pretty simple, no?  Git just takes the line-by-line changes and *combines* them.  As long as we changed *different lines* in file f1, Git can do this.  (More precisely, the changes must not overlap, nor abut, unless they overlap exactly and do exactly the same thing.)

If all goes well, Git takes the *combined* changes and applies them to the snapshot from commit `H`.  That combines our work: we keep our changes, and add theirs, whichever "side" of this we think of as ours and whichever one we think of as theirs.

The term Git uses for commit `H` is that it is the *merge base* commit.  The `git merge-base` command lets you see which commit Git chose, but for many merges, you don't need to bother.  Git does this all on its own after all.

The tricky cases come up when Git *can't* combine the changes on its own.  We'll skip over these hard cases here, to keep this answer shorter (well, shorter than it would be if we covered them).

So, let's do a `git merge` now.  We start by switching to whichever branch we want the merge commit to be "on" when we're done: the final commit is made like a regular `git commit`, with Git updating the branch name.  If we want the merge commit to  be "on" `br1`, we need to use `git switch` or `git checkout` to get there:

```
git switch br1
```

gives us:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The name `main` is about to be in the way, so I'm not going to draw it, but remember it's still there, pointing to `H`.  We'll now run:

```
git merge br2
```

The argument `br2` tells Git to *find* commit `L`, as pointed-to by name `br2`.  As with most things in Git, this merge isn't really about *branches* but rather about the *commits*, and Git needs to locate commit `L`.

Git already knows we're "on" commit `J`, because `HEAD` is attached to `br1` and `br1` points to `J`.  Git now uses the backwards arrows from commits `J` and `L` to work backwards to find the best *shared* commit.  (Note that this would find `H` as the shared commit even if we had more, or fewer, commits on one branch than on the other.  The actual algorithm for finding `H` is called the [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) algorithm.)  So Git finds commit `H` as the *merge base*.

Git now runs the two `git diff`s and combines the diffs and applies the combined results to `H`'s snapshot, to get a new snapshot.  This new snapshot goes into a new commit, which we'll call `M` (for Merge, and also the next letter available, which is why I made two commits on each branch):

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

The *only* thing special about commit `M` is that it has these two backwards arrows—or more precisely, that commit `M` contains, in its metadata, *both* hash IDs, for `J` and `L`.  (The *first* entry in this list of two hash IDs matters somewhat, and it's always the commit that the branch name *used to* point to.  But for now you probably don't have to care about this.)

**This is a true merge.**  The result of a true merge is that the new commit's *snapshot* holds the merge result, as made by the merge code (or *merge strategy*), and the new commit points backwards to both of the previous tip commits.  The other branch name—`br2` in this case—doesn't change, and in fact you don't have to use a branch name at all, if you're willing to type in (or cut and paste) raw commit hash IDs, with the obvious risk of typing it in wrong.

Moreover, since the name `br1` now lets Git find *both* commits `J` *and* `L`, by stepping backwards through both links from `M`, we're now safe to *delete the name `br2`* if we want:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

Git *needs* commit `L`'s hash ID to find commit `L`, but Git can *get* it from `M`, which Git can *find* from the name `br1`.

#### Non-merge "fast forward" operations

Let's go back to our saved repository (or otherwise get rid of `M`):

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

This time, instead of merging `br1` and `br2` with *each other*, let's run:

```
git switch main
git merge br1
```

so that we start with this as `git merge` fires up to find the merge base:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Let's work backwards from both commits `H` and `J`, to find the best *shared* commit.  If we look at `J`, it's only on `br1`, so that's no good.  Let's move back one to `I`.  It's still only on `br1`.  Let's move back one more to `H`.  Oh, look!  Commit `H` is on *both branches*, so it's obviously the merge base.

Now let's run our two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-H>   # what we changed on main
```

Wait a minute... this `git diff` output is *empty!*  Of course it's empty, commit `H` is identical to commit `H`.  It's *always going to be empty* if the merge base *is* the *current commit*.

The other diff won't be empty:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what they changed on br1
```

and the result of combining these two sets of differences will be the second set of differences.  If we go ahead and combine them and make a new commit `M`, we get this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

But the *snapshot* in `M` will exactly match the snapshot in `J`.  Git says to itself: *Gee, this kind of merge is stupid, why don't I cheat?*  And then Git cheats and does this instead:

```
          I--J   <-- br1, main (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H 
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

That is, `git merge` *doesn't bother to do any actual merging*, because the snapshot it will get is simply the snapshot in commit `J`.  Instead, Git drags the name `main` "fast forward" to point to commit `J` directly.

This kind of "fast forward" operation—presumably named after the ["fast forward" button on an old style tape recording device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_forward), which we now see as an icon on music and video players—is not really a merge at all.  In fact, Git can do it for operations that don't involve running `git merge` (specifically, `git push` and `git fetch` operations).  But when Git does it *because* **you** ran `git merge`, Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*.

*Not all merges can be fast-forward merges.*  Now that `main` and `br1` both point to commit `J`, a `git merge br2` has to do a real merge.

There's one more case we should cover here, when `git merge` says `already up to date` and does nothing.  Given:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

we'd get this message—it's not exactly an *error*, just information—if we ran `git merge main`.  Git would use its usual algorithm to find the merge base, which is commit `H`.  But that merge base commit is *behind* the current commit `J`.  Git can't move `br1` *forward* to `H`: moving `br1` to `H` would be backwards, and would "lose" commits `I-J` (without a name to find `J`'s hash ID, commit `J` gets "lost", and `J` is how we find `I`).  So you just get this message.

In summary

- Merging combines work.
- Some `git merge` operations have nothing to combine.  These either do nothing ("already up to date") or use the *fast-forward* trick to avoid doing anything *hard*, if you let them.

Adding `--no-ff` to your `git merge` command tells `git merge`: *No cheating!  Make a real merge even if you could cheat!*  Adding `--ff-only` tells `git merge`: *No doing any hard work!  Merge only if you can cheat!*  We won't worry about *why* you might want either of these just yet, just note that the flags exist.  If you don't use them, the default is *cheat if possible, otherwise do the hard work*.

#### Multiple Git repositories: `git clone` and `git fetch`

Let's look now at how `git fetch` works, starting with `git clone`.  We have some repository somewhere, maybe on Bitbucket or GitHub or whatever, and we'd like to do some work.  Git *requires* that we *make a new repository*, which we do with `git clone`.  This:

1. makes a new, empty directory for the repository: this is where our *working tree* will go, i.e., where we'll have files we can actually work on/with;
2. runs `git init` in this new empty directory to create a `.git` subdirectory that contains the two databases;
3. adds a *remote* named `origin` using `git remote add origin url`, which saves the URL for future use;
4. runs any additional configuration steps (usually none: this depends on options you give to `git clone`);
5. runs `git fetch origin`, which we'll explain in a moment; and
6. runs an initial checkout to *create* one branch name and get you started with some files from the selected commit.

The `git fetch` step—step 5 here—copies *all the commits* (or all the useful, find-able ones anyway) from the other Git repository, whose URL is saved under the name `origin`.  These commits, and all the necessary supporting objects, go into your new, initially-empty repository, in the objects database.  **It does not copy their branch names though.**  *Your* branch names, which will go into your names database here, are *yours*, not theirs.  Instead, it takes each of their *branch* names, like `main` and `develop` for instance, and *renames* them.

The renamed names get `origin/` shoved in front.  Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but I just call them *remote-tracking names* because they're not actually *branch* names.  They are your Git's method of remembering the *other* repository's branch names.  If they have a `main`, you now have an `origin/main`, that selects the same commit as their `main`.  If they have a `develop`, you now have an `origin/develop`.

When the fetch step is done, you have one remote-tracking name for each of their branch names.  You have *no* branch names of your own yet!  But now we get to step 6.  Your Git will *create* one new branch name.  Which one?  Well, that's up to you: you supply the name with your `-b` option, when you run `git clone`.  If you didn't supply a `-b` option, your Git software asks their (origin's) Git software which branch name they recommend.  Whatever name that is—usually `main` or `master`—that's the name your Git creates.  The commit you get as the *tip* commit for this branch is the *same commit* that *their* name selected.

This is a pretty long way around to get your own `main` pointing to commit `H`, just like their `main`, which is now your `origin/main`, but that's what `git clone` does.  If they had their `main` at commit `H`, well, you now have all their commits, and *one* branch of your own, also at commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
```

Note that you don't have a `develop`, but you *do* have an `origin/develop` that is just as good at finding commit `J`.

What you *can't* do is:

```
git switch origin/develop   # error!
```

You can't do this because `origin/develop` is a remote-tracking name, not a branch name.  If you want your own `develop`, you tell your Git to *make* one, and then switch to that:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

and then `git switch develop` removes the commit-`H` files and puts in the commit-`J` files and you have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

You may now make your own commits.  Let's say you do make one:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/develop
              \
               K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

You figure you're all set... but while you have been making commit `K`, maybe *someone else* was making new commits too!

You should now run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch`) to find out.  Your Git software will call up their (origin's) Git software and connect to their repository and see if they have any new commits.  If so, your Git will download the *new* commits and supporting objects—just the new stuff; re-used *files* in new commits don't need any downloading—and add that to your objects database.  Then your own Git software will update your own remote-tracking names, based on their updated *branch* names:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J--L   <-- origin/develop
              \
               K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Oh look!  They've added a new commit to *their* `develop`, so that your `origin/develop` points to new commit `L`.  But hang on a moment.  Let's draw *just* commits `J` through `L`, like this:

```
       K   <-- develop (HEAD)
      /
...--J
      \
       L   <-- origin/develop
```

This is a *branch*, sort of.  It's the kind of branch we mean when we mean "some commits that diverge".  Sometimes the word *branch* means *branch name*, sometimes it means *some set of commits*, and in this particular case it means *some set of commits that diverge and maybe need merging*.

#### The `git pull` command

Now that we understand fetch and merge, we can finally understand `git pull`, in its normal "fetch and the merge" mode.  We have:

```
       K   <-- develop (HEAD)
      /
...--J   <-- origin/develop
```

and we run `git pull`, which means:

1. run `git fetch` with appropriate arguments; then
2. run `git merge` with appropriate arguments

The `git fetch` step fetches from `origin` and results in:

```
       K   <-- develop (HEAD)
      /
...--J
      \
       L   <-- origin/develop
```

The `git merge` step merges with commit `L`, now found via `origin/develop`, which *requires a true merge*.  So that's what Git does:

```
       K
      / \
...--J   M   <-- develop (HEAD)
      \ /
       L   <-- origin/develop
```

You get exactly what you're seeing: Atlassian Sourcetree just draws the graph vertically, with newer commits towards the top, rather than horizontally, with newer commits towards the right.

*Before*, when you hadn't made a new commit, you had:

```
...--J   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

and you ran `git pull` and *if they had any new commits at all* it looked like this:

```
...--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
      \
       K   <-- origin/develop
```

and `git merge` *could and did cheat* and gave you:

```
...--J
      \
       K   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

with no new merge commit.  We can draw all this on one line, without any branching-and-merging, and Atlassian Sourcetree does so.

#### What can you do about this?

You *can* use `git rebase` *instead of* `git merge`.  There are a lot of caveats to this, and this answer is already very long, so I'm not going to get into any of the details.  Rebase is a sharp tool that must be used *carefully and correctly:* it's fundamentally easier to use `git merge` correctly (though it too is kind of a sharp tool, but `git rebase` effectively does multiple repeated internal merge operations, so that alone makes it more dangerous).

You can also *program* Git (well, "configure" it—same thing in some ways) to use `git rebase` as its second `git pull` command, *instead of* using `git merge`.  Or, you can set it up so that it uses `git merge --ff-only`, which we mentioned earlier without giving a motivation.  The main motivation here is that *if* `git pull` *can* do a fast-forward, that's almost always what you want it to do.  So configuring it to do that gets you a much more useful version of the `git pull` command.  (It probably should have been set up this way originally, way back in 2005, but it wasn't.)

My own preference, developed back in the mid aughts after getting burned multiple times by the then-somewhat-buggy `git pull`, is to *not run `git pull` at all*.  I run `git fetch`, see what `git fetch` fetched, and then choose my commands.  I'm slowly warming to a `git pull` with ff-only set, at least for some projects, though.